# Function in Javascript only breaks while loop if you type "yes" into the prompt the first time, but not the second

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a short function designed (optimally) to ask the same prompt/question over and over again while generating a new item from the array each time the answer is not "yes". It works well if you type "yes" after the first prompt, but will otherwise be stuck in a loop with the same item from the array (e.g. "Burger Fi") for each subsequent prompt. Typing "yes" will not break the loop after the first prompt. How can I generate new prompts with new items from the array each time you do not type "yes", while also breaking the loop and generating the alert once you do type "yes"?

```
var restList = ["The Big Easy", "Fruita Mix", "China Wok", "Burger Fi", "Yellow Dog Eats", "The Whole Enchilada", "The Little Greek", "4 Rivers", "Pub Subs", "Winter Garden Food Hall", "Blaze", "Polite Pig", "Chicken Fire", "Pho Saigon", "Thai Blossom"];
var restNumber = restList.length;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * restNumber);

function pickaPlace () {
    
    var answer = prompt("How about " + restList[random] + "?");

    while (answer !== "yes") {
        prompt("That's cool. How about " + restList[random] + "?");
    }

    alert("Awesome! Let's eat!");
     
}
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the return value of `prompt()` to `answer` in the loop

Answer (score 1):

this problem occurs because inside the `while` loop you didn't update the value of the `answer`

all you need is to update it

```
function pickaPlace () {
    
    var answer = prompt("How about " + restList[random] + "?");

    while (answer !== "yes") {
        answer = prompt("That's cool. How about " + restList[random] + "?");
    }

    alert("Awesome! Let's eat!");
     
}
```

for the random number problem it look that is generate only the first time
so to fix that you could make a simple function to generate a random number every time inside the loop

```
function randNumber(){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * restNumber);
}
```

after that, you could use it like this one

```
var restList = ["The Big Easy", "Fruita Mix", "China Wok", "Burger Fi", "Yellow Dog Eats", "The Whole Enchilada", "The Little Greek", "4 Rivers", "Pub Subs", "Winter Garden Food Hall", "Blaze", "Polite Pig", "Chicken Fire", "Pho Saigon", "Thai Blossom"];
var restNumber = restList.length;

function pickaPlace () {
    var answer = prompt("How about " + restList[randNumber()] + "?");
      
    while (answer !== "yes") {
        prompt("That's cool. How about " + restList[randNumber()] + "?");
    }

    alert("Awesome! Let's eat!");
     
}
```

At last, you could use `do..while` instead of `while` because it will run at least one time

```js
var restList = ["The Big Easy", "Fruita Mix", "China Wok", "Burger Fi", "Yellow Dog Eats", "The Whole Enchilada", "The Little Greek", "4 Rivers", "Pub Subs", "Winter Garden Food Hall", "Blaze", "Polite Pig", "Chicken Fire", "Pho Saigon", "Thai Blossom"];
var restNumber = restList.length;

function randNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * restNumber);
}

function pickaPlace() {
  var naswer = '';
  
  do {
    answer = prompt("That's cool. How about " + restList[randNumber()] + "?");
  } while (answer !== "yes");

  alert("Awesome! Let's eat!");
}

pickaPlace();
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. For further clarification, can you please explain how I can generate a new item from the array after each prompt that is not "yes"? It currently assigns the same randomized value after each prompt.

Comment: glad to helps, please check the answer again i update it

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `random` once and then using it multiple times. If you want a new value each time you use it, you need to set it again each time.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put random in a variable. It will keep the value and you won't be able to select another random number. Try this instead:

```js
var restList = ["The Big Easy", "Fruita Mix", "China Wok", "Burger Fi", "Yellow Dog Eats", "The Whole Enchilada", "The Little Greek", "4 Rivers", "Pub Subs", "Winter Garden Food Hall", "Blaze", "Polite Pig", "Chicken Fire", "Pho Saigon", "Thai Blossom"];
var restNumber = restList.length;

function pickaPlace() {

  var answer = prompt("How about " + restList[Math.floor(Math.random() * restNumber)] + "?");
  while (answer != "yes") {
    answer = prompt("That's cool. How about " + restList[Math.floor(Math.random() * restNumber)] + "?");
  }
  alert("Awesome! Let's eat!");
}

pickaPlace();
```